# perl Net::IMAP::Client: how to express complex search query

Tags: perl, imap

I am using `Net::IMAP::Client` to clean up my mail folders on my providers host.
At first I search the messages matching some criteria:

The doc says:

> search($criteria, $sort, $charset)
>
> Executes the "SEARCH" or "SORT" IMAP commands (depending on wether
> $sort is undef) and returns the results as an array reference
> containing message ID-s.
>
> Note that if you use `$sort` and the IMAP
> server doesn't have this capability, this method will fail. Use
> "capability" to investigate.
>
> - $criteria
>
>   Can be a string, in which case it is passed literally to the IMAP command (which can be "SEARCH" or "SORT").
>
> It can also be an hash reference, in which case keys => values are
> collected into a   > string and values are properly quoted, i.e.:
>
> ```
> { subject => 'foo',
>   from    => 'bar' }
> ```
>
> will translate to:
>
> ```
> 'SUBJECT "foo" FROM "bar"'
> ```
>
> which is a valid IMAP SEARCH query.
>
> If you want to retrieve all messages (no search
> criteria) then pass 'ALL' here.

I need to search for all mails where subject matches 'this' or 'that'.

This is what I tried:

```
{ subject => 'this', subject => 'that' }
```

But it correctly returns only mails with 'that' in subject line.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

In a hash, each key is unique. `{ subject => 'this', subject => 'that' }`
results in the same hash as `{ subject => 'that' }`, which explains why you only get emails starting with `that`.

I would suggest to use a string instead of a hash reference, and use `OR` to combine multiple `SUBJECT`:

```
"OR SUBJECT this SUBJECT that"
```

(use quotes around `this` and `that` if they contain spaces)